How to avoid Rasa Form filling different slots that have the same intent?
I have a form that colleccts some information from the customer. After the 4 slots have been filled, I run an action to clean and validate the values. Then, the bot presents the results to the customer and asks if they are correct. If reply is yes, the data is saved, otherwise, the slots are set to null and the form is run again. Everything is fine, except when the customer needs to correct something. The bot gets lost.
The way I thought to get the bot to ask for correction was to set a slot 'confirmation_requested', boolean type, initial value=false. When the validation action is run, it sets the value to true. In rules, when 'confirmation_requested' is true and the intent is affirm, save the values. When the itent is deny, sets the slot to null and restart the form.
The problem I found was in the last question of the form (cnpj), the itent is affirm or deny. Whenever this slot is filled, the 'confirmation_requested' is filled with the same value (althought it is a requested_slot). How do I avoid to have different slots to be filled when the same itent is perceived?
rules:


rule: Activate health insurance form
steps:

intent: greet
action: utter_greet
action: health_insurance_form
active_loop: health_insurance_form


rule: Submit form and validate data
condition:

active_loop: health_insurance_form
slot_was_set:

requested_slot: null
steps:


action: health_insurance_form
active_loop: null
action: action_validate_and_clean_data
slot_was_set:

confirmation_requested: true


action: utter_confirm_data


rule: Handle positive confirmation
condition:

slot_was_set:

confirmation_requested: true
requested_slot: null
steps:


intent: affirm
action: action_save_user_data
slot_was_set:

confirmation_requested: false




rule: Handle negative confirmation
condition:

slot_was_set:

confirmation_requested: true
requested_slot: null
steps:


intent: deny
action: action_reset_slots
action: health_insurance_form
active_loop: health_insurance_form
slot_was_set:

confirmation_requested: false





domain:
cnpj:
type: text
mappings:
- type: from_intent
  intent: affirm
  value: Yes
- type: from_intent
  intent: deny
  value: No
  conditions:
  - active_loop: health_insurance_form
    requested_slot: cnpj


confirmation_requested:
type: bool
initial_value: false
mappings:
- type: from_intent
  intent: affirm
  value: true
  conditions:
  - active_loop: null
    requested_slot: null
- type: from_intent
  intent: deny
  value: false
  conditions:
  - active_loop: null
    requested_slot: null

